# Why is an html.erb file called after a controller is called?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I don't quite understand the flow of an MVC. A request of a page goes to a route and that route calls an action in a controller. But then why is a view called after that? I don't really understand which code calls the view and displays it to the user.

```
root 'controllername#index'

def index
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A controller action will search for a view with the same name e.g. controller action `index` will search for views such as `index.html.erb` and `index.html.haml` in their associated directory. To have a controller action without a view, something like `render :nothing => true` can be used.

More information can be found in the [Action View guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_view_overview.html).